# How to Fix/Rehabilitate Soft Plastic Retaining Clip

Tags: plastic-clip

Having a small problem trying to state this clearly...anyhoo:

When replacing cabin air filter for my car (2007 Toyota 4-Runner), it is necessary to get behind the glove box (or whatever it is called now) which requires removing a piston/strut thingy on the passenger side of box.  The YT video linked here starts at about the right place to make this clearer:

https://youtu.be/NjfycJTJG7M?si=qG___HDObfcaBxJP

But the "mechanic" that did this 1st time a while back didn't understand and just pushed the box down until the soft plastic retaining clip that holds the piston/strut thingy at top gave way and seems to have permanently deformed. (see pic attached.)  It has never really worked to retain that thingy since I've owned the vehicle (purchased used) such that the glove box occasionally falls out farther than it should when the piston thingy drops off the retaining clip.  And since that retaining clip is an integrated part of the plastic housing around the compartment, it can't be individually replaced.

**So my question is: are there any approaches or suggestions as to how I can get this thing to work as originally intended?**  Note that space/thing are *really* hard to get at even with a couple of fingers...it's like playing Operation (tm).  For instance, I've tried to place a small folded wad of paper in between the clip prongs to hold the clip more open...I found it pretty much intractable to get at it with enough precision such that it would stay, especially when trying to get the piston thingy to hang back on it.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about cars and there is a stack for that.

Comment: This should be posted on https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ Unfortunately, no simple way to just move it, but that is where it belongs.

Comment: Moderators can request migration. Unfortunately the "request migration" for the rest of us is (and always has been) utterly useless, unless an actual question that belongs on the diy.meta site comes along, and I've seen darn few of those. Some metric like "user requesting migration has at least X rep on both stacks" would appear to control abuse, but I recall vaguely getting shouted down for suggesting it on one of the higher up meta stacks, so <bleep> it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal well I do have over 20k rep on both... If that is sufficient for X? But more seriously that would be a good metric. Wonder who had "reasons" to shout it down??

Comment: I did post on MechanicStack...but, this seemed general enough in nature, i.e. how to fix a plastic thing, and less about actual "real" automotive/mechanic stuff that I thought the DIY stack (that's in the URL and how I have always thought of this Stack) was appropriate *enough*.  Kind of like if I got a rip in my *car* leather seat or if I spilled some staining fluid on my *car* carpets...issues is not really about cars, but more general DIY fixes, i.e. how to fix a leather tear or stain n a carpet.  Anyhoo...Thanks, though...

Answer (score 1):

Very, very, carefully apply heat. Enough heat will allow the thing to bend and stay put when cooled. Too much heat will melt things too much and cause further damage to the impractical to replace plastic dash.

The question probably belongs on another stack, though.

Comment: I did post on MechanicStack...but, this seemed general enough in nature, i.e. how to fix a plastic thing, and less about actual "real" automotive/mechanic stuff that I thought the DIY stack (that's in the URL and how I have always thought of this Stack) was appropriate *enough*.  Kind of like if I got a rip in my *car* leather seat or if I spilled some staining fluid on my *car* carpets...issues is not really about cars, but more general DIY fixes, i.e. how to fix a leather tear or stain n a carpet.  Thanks for your response, though...always appreciated :--)